# Quick replace #N/A by 0 when vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I use `vlookup` a lot in excel.

The problem is with `#N/A` value when the seek value is not found.

In that case, we often replace it by 0 using

```
if(isna(vlookup(what,range,column,false));0; vlookup(what,range,column;false))
```

which repeat **vlookup(what,range,column,false)** twice and make the formula look ugly & dummy to me.

Do you have other work around for this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Which version of Excel? In Excel 2007 or later you can use IFERROR function like this

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B2:E3,4,0),0)`

Comment: correctomundo +1

Comment: @Raystafarian Cannot get what you mean :)

Comment: @barry houdini Horay!

Comment: @NamGiVU I was just agreeing with barry's answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`IFNA`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFNA-function-6626c961-a569-42fc-a49d-79b4951fd461) if you only want to detect #N/A errors.

```
=IFNA(Formula,0)
```

This will display `0` instead of the #N/A error.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty powerful, and I've been scouring the web for a while to get this question answered. In my case, however, I don't want to replace the `#N/A` with a `0`, but instead, I want to use alternate information. In my case, if the `VLOOKUP` doesn't find anything, I want it to use the contents of another cell. (I'm using Excel 2010, but that shouldn't matter) Assume that my formula in cell `E3` on `Sheet1`, and the data I want to pull is somewhere on `Sheet2`. If there is no data to be found on `Sheet2`, then I want my cell to use data from `Sheet1`.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!B2:E3,4,FALSE),Sheet1!D3)
```

*To the original responder, THANK YOU. You made my life a bit easier tonight. I hope my rambling expansion on your answer helps someone, too!*