# Excel vlookup reference purposely missing shows #N/A - stop it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a cell which does a vlookup.

But the table to which it refers is always changing and when the specific value is there is shows fine.

But when the value isn't there it shows #N/A - how can I get it to stop this and just display nothing?

Example: =VLOOKUP($P5,GW30!$CI:$CL,2,FALSE) and P5 = Arsenal

So when Arsenal play at home I get a value and it's ok. But when they play away they are listed in a different column and I get a #N/A

I need to stop it showing #N/A please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick replace #N/A by 0 when vlookup](http://superuser.com/questions/397104/quick-replace-n-a-by-0-when-vlookup)

Answer (score 9):

You want to use the [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($P5,GW30!$CI:$CL,2,FALSE),"")
```

If there's no error, it will return the value as normal. If there is, it will return what's after the comma, in this case an empty string.

Comment: I wonder if this also applies to google spreadsheet (I ahve the same problem)

Comment: Note for some older versions of excel (and maybe Google spreadsheets), if `iferror()` isn't available, just do `If(IsError([formula]),"",[formula])`

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap your formula with the `iferror` condition and set the default value for the error condition to be blank e.g.

```
iferror(VLOOKUP($P5,GW30!$CI:$CL,2,FALSE),"")
```